# A hamburger menu doesn't dissappear after click

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, hamburger-menu

I'm facing the problem with the burger menu. I want to make it disappear after clicking on the menu position and away of the menu as well. I am a beginner. Thanks in advance.

CSS

```
 .burger {
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s ease-out;
  }

  .burger.active .line:first-child {
    transform: translateX(+300px);
  }

  #menu {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    top: 100px;
    height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 75%;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: 0.3s ease-out;
  }

  #menu.active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    transition: 0.3s ease-out;
  }

  #menu li {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: normal;
  }

  #menu li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

Javascript

```
document.querySelectorAll(".filterable_cards img").forEach((image) => {
        image.onclick = () => {
          document.querySelector(".popup-image").style.display = "block";
          document.querySelector(".popup-image img").src =
            image.getAttribute("src");
        };
      });
```

HTML

```
 <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">O mnie</a></li>
      <li><a href="#graphics">Grafika</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="burger">
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
```

Mostly I need a help with the Javascript code I think.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It seems you want to hide the burger menu after clicking a menu item. You may need to add an event listener on each menu item and toggle the `active` class when menu items are clicked. Here's how you can do this:

```js
// JavaScript

// Get the menu items and burger element
let menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('#menu li a');
let burger = document.querySelector('.burger');

// Add an event listener to each menu item
menuItems.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // When a menu item is clicked, remove 'active' class from #menu and burger
    document.querySelector('#menu').classList.remove('active');
    burger.classList.remove('active');
  });
});

// Add click event for the burger menu
burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // On click, toggle 'active' class for #menu and burger
  document.querySelector('#menu').classList.toggle('active');
  burger.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

You can also hide the menu when you click outside:

```js
// JavaScript

document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let isClickInsideMenu = document.querySelector('#menu').contains(event.target);
    let isClickOnBurger = burger.contains(event.target);

    if (!isClickInsideMenu && !isClickOnBurger) {
        // The click was outside the menu and burger, hide them
        document.querySelector('#menu').classList.remove('active');
        burger.classList.remove('active');
    }
});
```

The above code will track a click event on each menu item. When a click event is detected, it will remove the active class from the menu and hamburger button, causing them to hide. The changes in the `.active` class will affect the CSS transform property, providing a slide-in/slide-out animation.

I recommend adding this JavaScript code to the end of your HTML body tag or placing it inside a function that is called after the `DOMContentLoaded` event, to ensure all elements have been rendered to the DOM before the script is run.

All my best in your learning journey.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I wanted. Now I have a lot to study about Javascript. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

```
const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
const menu = document.querySelector("#menu");

burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
  menu.classList.toggle("active");
});

document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (event.target === burger || event.target === menu) {
    return;
  }

  menu.classList.remove("active");
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Your code is working but it haven't solved my problem totally. The code didn't affect the three hamburger lines - while clicking on them the menu does not show. The animation of the upper line disappearing while showing the menu. I added the HTML code to my main post. Could you take a look once again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).